# Keeping References During Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera

I am using a `Camera`, and I call the `open` method on it in `onCreate` in an activity. When the activity is destroyed, I release the `Camera`. However, a fragment in the activity may be using the `Camera` (for example, making the flash blink repeatedly), so when the orientation changes from portrait to landscape, for example, the `Camera` is released (because the activity is destroyed) and the reference is set to null, causing a NPE to be thrown from the fragment. How do I keep the reference to the `Camera` during orientation change (so that the flash keeps blinking) **and** release the `Camera` when the activity is destroyed (for example, when the user clicks the Back button)?

```
public static Camera camera = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

  if (camera == null) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    if (camera == null) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unable to get back-facing camera.");
      finish();
    }
  }
  // ..
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  if (camera != null) {
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
  }
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

For api 13 or higher `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
As of api 13 screen size also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape mode

So this way your activity will not be destroyed during orientation change

Comment: Point of this is that, you are telling android that you will handle these changes in your activity and don't need to implement default behavior